# How to add a dimension to a measure group in a linked (local) cube?

Tags: ssas

I have a cube 'Big' which links (among others) the cube 'Small'. Both are in the same database. I've now added a new dimension to a measure group in 'Small', and would like it to show up for the same measure group in 'Big'.

How can I achieve this?

The Dimension Usage tab for 'Big' won't let me add a relationship between the measure group and dimension, saying 'Regular relationships in the current database between non-linked (local) dimensions and linked measure groups cannot be edited. These relationships can only be created through the wizard'.

Both cubes, and the new dimension are in the same solution in VS.

This is for Analysis Services 2005 and VS 2005.

Update: I've solved the problem by deleting the linked measure groups from 'Big' and re-adding them. However, this had the unwanted side-effect that existing relationships between these measure groups and dimensions not defined in 'Small' had to be re-added manually.

Comment: Are you using linked objects for your measure groups in one of your cubes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. 'Big' contains linked measure groups (defined in 'Small').